# Fatal error while updating coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm receiving a fatal error while updating the coldfusion10 `'C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\db\slserver54\bin\libeay32.dll (The process  cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)'`. Following is the entire message,

```
Failed to copy hotfix files:C:\Documents and Settings\Default 
User\762024.tmp\dist\cfusion 
Status: FATAL ERROR 
Additional Notes: FATAL ERROR - Failed to 
copy the hotfix files to the target location:C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion 
FATAL ERROR - 
C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\db\slserver54\bin\libeay32.dll (The process 
cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
```

If someone could let me know as how to resolve this & make the update a successful one I will be more than happy.

Comment: How did you try to update it?

Comment: You can try reading this http://www.carehart.org/presentations/Updating_hotfixing_CF.pdf

Comment: Better suited for ServerFault.

Comment: Seems like a permission issue. C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\ should have access to C:\ColdFusion10\.

Answer (score 1):

I received this exact error as well.  To resolve it, I went into the Services Management Console and stopped all the ColdFusion services except the Application Server and restarted the installation process.  After the successful update I restarted the services I stopped.

Comment: I stopped all CF services and some succeeded, but others still Fatal Error like OP's